# In NativeScript Angular why aren't these icons showing up centered?

Tags: android, ios, angular, nativescript, font-awesome

I would like to use FontAwesome fonts in a NativeScript + Angular app.

I have followed the instructions [on how to include fonts](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/icon-fonts)

I added the FontAwesome.ttf file to the fonts directory and added

```
.fa {
font-family: "FontAwesome", FontAwesome;
}
```

to app.css.

And then I apply the fa style to a label that has as its text the code for the icon I want. I would like the icon to be centered in the circle.

I've set up a working example in the [NativeScript Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=d2yOnk&v=12)

Any character that has the 'fa' style applied is not centered in the circle. This happens under both Android and iOS.

Am I doing something incorrectly or is this a bug?

I have tried both the current version of FontAwesome and the older one that I've included in the Playground link. I have also tried Material Design Icons.

I do notice that this does not appear to happen in the [NativeScript + Angular Plugins Showcase app](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-pluginshowcase) which is based on Angular 6 where as I am working with Angular 7.1.

[image: Why aren't these icons centered in the circles?]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it could be the issue with font itself, the vector in the font comes with its own positioning / margin. A workaround could be applying `circle` class (rounded edges) to the label's parent and set `verticalAlignment` to `center`

```
        <StackLayout class="circle" verticalAlignment="center">
            <Label class="fa" text="&#xf018;"></Label>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout class="circle" verticalAlignment="center">
            <Label class="fa" text="XX"></Label>
        </StackLayout>
```

[Updated Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=d2yOnk&v=13)

Comment: That makes perfect sense. I have verified that this works. Thank you!